# Getting error in giving font parameter in imageloadfont

Tags: php

I am using `imageloadfont` function for create dynamic image. I am giving `AARDV.TTF` font file as parameter in imageloadfont file. Below the code i am using :

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(750,600);
$title = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 240, 255);
$font = imageloadfont(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_motivator/images/font/AARDV.TTF');
$text = "Some text here";

imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 15, 20, $title, $font, $text);
```

When the above code is running i got an error message

```
Warning: imageloadfont() [function.imageloadfont]: gd warning: product of memory allocation multiplication would exceed INT_MAX, failing operation gracefully
```

How I solve this error give me any idea

Answer (score -3):

your `imagettftext()` function should be written like `imageTTFtext()` i think the library its case sensitive.